# What will be the output when "ifconfig" command is entered after running the 6lbr, installed on RPi?

Tags: pi-2, raspbian-wheezy

im having some issues with accessing the 6lbr web server page. I just need to know what is the output you get once you checked your interfaces by entering "ifconfig". In mine, I just get only the details about loopback interface and eth0 interface. I really appreciate your help because I have stucked in this point for more than 2 weeks now :(
Im using raspberry pi 2 and raspbian wheezy is installed

Comment: `I just get only the details about loopback interface and eth0 interface` - what else were you expecting?

Comment: Doesnt it show any details related to tap0 , br0 interfaces? Btw Im running 6lbr in the router mode.

Comment: `ifconfig` is deprecated. You should use `ip` from the *iproute2* package. Why do you expect that a web server will install a virtual private network (interface **tap0**) and a bridge (interface **br0**)? Web server I know only use the available interfaces (e.g. **eth0**). Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Ingo thanks for the comment. When I install the 6lbr, I added these configuration to the 6lbr.conf file.  "MODE=ROUTER

      RAW_ETH=1
      BRIDGE=0
      DEV_BRIDGE=br0
      DEV_TAP=tap0
      DEV_ETH=eth0
      RAW_ETH_FCS=0

      DEV_RADIO=/dev/ttyACM0
      BAUDRATE=115200

      LOG_LEVEL=3"  So I suspect that when 6lbr service is started, it should show the interfaces related to tap0 and br0. Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: Seems to be a special case for 6lbr but not for Raspberry Pi. Look with `ip link show` if you see other interfaces. If not then 6lbr doesn't work as expected. Is there an installation instruction or an image for Raspberry Pi?

Comment: @Ingo , I used the following link for the instructions. https://sunmaysky.blogspot.com/2015/08/setup-6lbr-to-run-6lowpan-with-cc2531.html?m=1  So do you think according to the configuration I added to the 6lbr.conf file, it should show those interfaces too? When I checked the 6lbr.log file it shows the service started finely.

Comment: Huh.. you are installing from source. Then there it's difficult to say what happens without knowing something about it. Yes, if the program creates interfaces you should see them on the operating system. Maybe you will find something in `journalctl -b -e`.